# How to define a boolean operator to compare an exact attribute of a class?

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
class Student
{private:
    char _name[20];
    char _no[20];
    int _score;
public:
    Student(int score){_score = score;}
    bool operator>(Student s);
};

bool Student::operator>(Student s, Student b)
{   return s._score > b._score;
};

int main() {
    Student a(70);
    Student b(75);
    cout<<(b>a)<<endl;
}
```

I just started on C++ and have a problem with simple codes.
The error then says that 'bool Student::operator>(Student, Student)' must take exactly one argument.

Comment: How about `bool Student::operator > (Student b)
{   return this._score > b._score;
};`

Comment: Your definition needs to match your declaration and only take a single parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operators inside the class take their first argument (if there are two arguments) from the class object itself.

Put the operator outside the class

```
bool operator>(Student s, Student b)
{   
return s._score > b._score;
};
```

Or, the operator inside:

```
bool Student::operator>(Student b)
{  
 return _score > b._score;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared the operator as a class method with 1 argument and the definition must match:

```
bool Student::operator>(Student rhs)
{   return _score > rhs._score;
};
```

---

Not related to your question: you should definitely use `std:: string` instead of C char arrars